# Is it possible using Tensorflow to create a neural network for input/output mapping?

Tags: python, tensorflow, supervised-learning

I am currently using tensorflow to create a neural network, that replicates the function of creating a certain output given an input.

The input in this case is a sampled audio, and the audio is generating MFCC features. Know for each file what the corresponding MFCC feature, is, but aren't sure how i should setup the neural network.

I am following this guide/tutorial http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/09/urban-sound-classification-neural-networks-tensorflow.html/2

It which it says that the neural network is setup as such

```
training_epochs = 5000
n_dim = tr_features.shape[1]
n_classes = 10
n_hidden_units_one = 280 
n_hidden_units_two = 300
sd = 1 / np.sqrt(n_dim)
learning_rate = 0.01
```

My question here is how i define the number of classes? I mean, the real values I've computed aren't divided into classes, but is a decimal number, so should I just create multiple networks with different number of classes, and choose the one which has the smallest error compared to the original value, or is there a tensorflow command that can do that, as I am doing supervised learning..

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks could be use for classification tasks or regression tasks. In [tutorial](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/09/urban-sound-classification-neural-networks-tensorflow.html/2), the author wants to classify sounds into 10 different categories. So the neural networks have 10 output neurons (`n_classes`) and each of their activation value give the probability of membership to a class for an input sound.

In our case, you want to map a given sound  with a decimal number (that's right ?), so it's a regression task : the neural network have to learn an unknown function. The number of output neurons has to be equal to the output dimension of our unknown function (1 if it's just a decimal number).

So if you want to keep the same architecture to our regression task, just set `n_classes = 1` and modify `y_` to

```
y_ = tf.matmul(h_2,W) + b
```

because `tf.nn.softmax` convert the final score to probability (it's good for classification but not for regression)

Comment: OP also has to modify a cost since the one in tutorial `cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(y_), reduction_indices=[1]))` makes no sense for regression.

Comment: Damn, I forgot the coss function. Thanks @lejlot !